# How to erase SAS SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, sata, scsi

For SATA SSD, I know that there exists an open source program named [hdparm](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) for secure erase by issuing ATA command and this tool has been embedded within linux operating system. For SAS SSD, I want to know whether there is a similar tool that can be used for secure erase for all kinds of SAS SSD. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It varies by vendor, but mostly the `sg_format` tool (as found in the `sg3_utils` package) will suffice.

[Sandisk states in their support system:](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8502/~/secure-erase-or-scsi-command-supports-on-the-sandisk-lightning-sas-ssds)

> All SanDisk Lightning SSDs are SAS and support the SCSI format unit
>   command which will securely erase all user data.